# Matching up cam lock or cam and groove coupling

Tags: mechanical-engineering, piping

I am trying to select new hose cam locks to connect to cam locks on an existing pipe system. There seem to be a lot of different types of cam locks as I've searched for them, so I am unsure how I distinguish between them. Are there different swages, groove radii, or other variables that I need to measure so I can match up new cam locks, or are cam locks all the same and only vary by diameter? If there are measurable variables, is there a chart available that lists these variables (e.g. like the charts for measuring steel C-channel weights)?

Comment: Are you talking about cam-locks as in locks that keep a door closed or as in single pole power connectors? Just because both are common terms.

Comment: I'm talking about pipe or hose connectors. And I think I may have found my answer on Wikipedia. Oops. I should have stayed persistent.

Comment: Ah, a third option! If you want to post an answer based on what you found, it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Camlock connectors are capable of carrying liquids, powders and granules and are interchangeable with all other cam and groove couplings made to the same standard (A-A-59326A – formally MIL-C-27487),[1] ensuring compatibility with couplings made to the same specification.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camlock_(fluid_fitting)